# Rails 3 select multiple values from table joined multiple times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rails-activerecord

Let's say I have ActiveRecord models A, B and C:

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base    
    belongs_to :c
    has_one :b
end

class B < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :c
end

class C < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :a
    has_one :c
end
```

The database tables look like:

```
Table a:
id (auto increment) | b_id | c_id

Table b:
id (auto increment) | c_id

Table c:
id (auto increment)
```

Now I want,

```
SELECT a.id, b.id, c.id, b_c.id
    FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON a.b_id = b.id
INNER JOIN c ON a.c_id = c.id
INNER JOIN c b_c b.c_id = b_c.id
```

I know I can do it by using SQL directly in `joins` and `select`:

```
A.joins(:b, :c).joins('INNER JOIN c b_c b.c_id = b_c.id')
```

Is there a rails way to do it?
Can his be in Rail-like syntax? Something like:

```
A.joins(:c, :b => :c).select(:c => :id).select(:b => { :c => :id})
```

Comment: Not able to follow your question. Can you explain it a little bit more?

Comment: Edited. Is the question clear now?